# class construction in R

Tags: r

I have the following question for class construction -

```
a <- function(...){ do something results in array(n,m)}
```

now, to create aclass I have done the following

```
a <- function(...){do something results in array(n,m) 
new("aclass", slot n,j i= array[,j]}
```

This works but then I am not too sure that this is best way to do create the class when developing software. It seems that the downside is that the function will always serve as a constructor but then again need the results of the function in an object anyhow.  Am I on the right track with this or have I missed something?

Comment: Two problems. Names should not contain spaces, and if there is no "a class" then calling `new` should fail. See `?Classes`, `?setClass`, and `?new`

Comment: DWin, thanks, Okay, fixed the technical point in the question the class name does not have spaces and the function does not fail because there is a class using setClass("aclass", representation(...)).  Its just that the function that creates this class using new class at the end is over 150 lines of code and I just don't see examples making classes this way. So, I am a little uncertain.

Comment: So you are really asking us to hack into your system to see what you are talking about?

Comment: `lm()` is an example of a function that takes many lines of code and then produces an (S3) object (of class `lm`). With S4 classes there are usually restrictions needed for, e.g., inheritance to work. So `new("aclass")` must succeed in producing a valid class. This implies that there is a very simple constructor in addition to your complicated constructor -- perhaps it is a semantic convenience to call your function `a` a constructor, rather than a logical necessity.